# Array of Sql values in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

in my Rails project I am trying to use the following query in a search `form_tag`

```
Student.joins(:courses).where(@params.joins(','), @values)
```

where `params` and values are dynamically constructed arrays since there are some optional parameters in the search. An example from my code:

```
  if params[:date_begin] != ''
    @params.push " courses.date_begin  >=  ? "
    @values.push params[:date_begin]
  end
```

The problem is the `@values` array is being considered as one argument and raises this error:

> wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2)

How do I tell it to consider the array elements separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about build query this way:

```
scope = Student.joins(:courses)

if params[:date_begin].present?
  scope = scope.where(" courses.date_begin  >=  ? ", params[:date_begin])
end

scope
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to splat array

```
Student.joins(:courses).where(@params.joins(','), *@values)
```

Comment: I ended up using the above answer but yours too works great. Thanks a lot

Comment: This answer better answers the original question and IMO is cleaner

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the array like so:

```
Student.joins(:courses).where(@params.join('AND'), *@values)
```

(Note you also need to change `joins` to `join` and the comma to `AND`).